# AttributeError: module 'scater' has no attribute 'normalize'

Tags: r, python, scran, rpy2

I am using `rpy2` to run normalization using `scran` package. After calling `computeSumFactors` I want to do the actual normalization calling `normalize()` function from `scater` package:

```
def normalize(counts):
utils = importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) 

packnames = ('Matrix', 'limSolve')
names_to_install = [x for x in packnames if not isinstalled(x)]
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))

base = importr('base')
base.source('http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocInstaller = importr('BiocInstaller')

biocInstaller.biocLite('SingleCellExperiment', suppressUpdates=True)
biocInstaller.biocLite('scran', suppressUpdates=True)
biocInstaller.biocLite('scater', suppressUpdates=True)

sceLib = importr("SingleCellExperiment")
scranLib = importr("scran")
scaterLib = importr("scater")
named_list = robjects.r.list(counts=counts)
sce = sceLib.SingleCellExperiment(named_list)

try:
    clusters = scranLib.quickCluster(sce)
    sce = scaterLib.computeSumFactors(sce, cluster=clusters, positive=True)
except rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError:
    print("fewer cells than the minimum cluster size, so no quickCluster is run")
    sce = scranLib.computeSumFactors(sce, positive=True)

----> sce = scaterLib.normalize(sce, logExprsOffset=1)
```

Everything runs fine except the last line which gives the error:

> AttributeError: module 'scater' has no attribute 'normalize'

This is strange since that is what I am supposed to do actually according to [docs](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/scran/inst/doc/scran.html).

I suspect that maybe I am loading a wrong `scran` version? I do not know though neither how to check the version number, nor how to install a specific one. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the following:

```
sce = scaterLib.normalizeSCE(sce, log_exprs_offset=1)
```

And it is working. I am afraid though that it is a wrong way to go.

I tried to get the normalized matrix but it retrieved the initial raw counts one:

```
sce = scaterLib.normalizeSCE(sce, log_exprs_offset=1)
mtx_norm_r = robjects.r.assay(sce)
mtx_norm = np.array(mtx_norm_r)
```

So, something is definitely wrong here. Either I am retrieving the normalized matrix in the wrong way or the normalization was not run correctly. I tried the following method for retrieval but no luck:

```
mtx_norm_r = sceLib.normcounts(sce)
```

> RRuntimeError: Error in assay(object, i = exprs_values) : 
>     'assay(, i="character", ...)' invalid subscript 'i'
>   'normcounts' not in names(assays())

I found a way to get the version numbers using `getNamespaceVersion()` function:

```
robjects.r.getNamespaceVersion('scater')
```

The versions are:

```
scater - 1.8.4
scran - 1.8.4
SingleCellExperiment - 1.2.0
```

They are the newest as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to the normalized values using `logcounts` function in the following way:

```
mtx_norm_r = sceLib.logcounts(sce)
mtx_norm = np.array(mtx_norm_r)
```

Since I used `log_exprs_offset=1` the field that I needed to use is `logcounts`, otherwise it should be `normcounts` which I found [here](https://rdrr.io/bioc/scater/man/normalize.html).

Comment: Maybe you know it but you can read the help page for each function using `?name_of_function` on the terminal (There is no need to consult an online help page that might not match your version of the package).

Comment: But I can not check it in `spyder`

Comment: I don't know what is spyder but if it can run R is run you can.

Comment: It can not be done, or I do not know how anyway. It is `rpy2` python library that translates objects between `R` and `python` and the documentation is often not clear and detailed enough, in my view, probably because not that many people use it. Spyder is just IDE for `python` from `anaconda`